# indicators that move asset prices

Tags: indicator

Wondering which economic indicators move tradable asset (like equities or bonds) prices substantially (more then 0.5%) when they are published.
For example the weekly unemployment rate update usually moves the SNP500 index. Also references to where I can find a person to pay to get answers to this question would also be appreciated

List of indicators can be found here: https://tradingeconomics.com/calendar

Comment: Hi. One thing is that (at least theoretically) it is seldomly the publication of an indicator as you call it that ‘moves’ prices, but some deviation from its expected level. Furthermore, different market segments are ‘driven’ by different news. Think about the influence of publication of FOMC decision on the overall market vs publication of buying managers indices vs publication of, say, unemployment rates... maybe you could be a bit more specific or rephrase to a certain market /segment?

Comment: Yeah of course, deviation from the expected level, and I'm wondering about all market segments.

Comment: The *Monthly* employment/unemployment number is the most important release and the FOMC is the second most important, in terms of the effect on markets. (I would put the weekly unemployment  and others much lower in the importance scale).

Comment: Are you sure that there are no other indicators?

Comment: Which indicator does the FOMC public that is the most useful? and what asset prices does it move?

Comment: There are 8 FOMC meetings a year, and a press release is issued after each meeting which can move both stock and bond markets. Of course several other economc announcements are important too, so my answer is very incomplete.

Comment: got it, thanks, who can I talk to / pay to get a more complete answer?

Answer (score 3):

Several banks used to publish regular updates on which economic indicators had the greatest impact on markets. From a very old piece (2007), the indicators that had the largest impact on Bunds 10 mins after release were: NFP; US GDP, ISM mfg, core CPI, ifo, ZEW, DE GDP, Philly Fed, ISM non-mfg, UoM. Of course, results will depend on how you measure, what markets you look at, how you control for other variables, etc.

Comment: can you link to an example? what keywords should i be searching for? thanks in advance

Comment: I don't know of any material that's publicly available. You might find something by searching for some combinations of: market OR asset price AND response OR reaction AND economic data.